# Products only appear when saved in Magento

Tags: magento

I have imported 3,000+ products into Magento successfully.

The products are all present and correct in the back end.

But none of the products appear in the front end.

All the products are:

- Visible in Catalog.
- Enabled.
- Have a stock quantity of 10.
- In Stock.
- Assigned various Categories.
- Assigned to the correct website.

I have refreshed my Cache and Indices, just to make sure. But the products do not appear on the front end at all.

---

As requested here are the columns used in my CSV file:

`status type    attribute_set   tax_class_id    visibility  qty     is_in_stock     product_id      name    short_description   description     rrp     weight  mpn     gtin    sku     price   color_text  size    stock_weight    category_ids    brand   small_image`

---

**But there is a solution!**

If I view a product in Megento's back end, and simply hit `Save`, it appears on the front end.

Does anyone have a better solution for me, than opening up all 3000+ products and hitting save on each one of them?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can select all products from grid and select update attributes section. just update visibility again.

Comment: sorry, that didnt work :(

Comment: Please provide here the CSV files' columns

Comment: This is because product object is not set properly after import. quick solution is ....go to system->configuration->Catalog->inventory->product stock option->Manage Stock = no  this works for me .. :)

Comment: sorry, that didnt work either :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that this is because Magento is defaulting value that are not present in your imported products.

What I would do is :

1. Choose a buggy product and note its `entity_id`
2. Replace this `entity_id` in the query below (find and replace `275` would work) :

   ```
   select entity_id, attribute_id, store_id from `catalog_product_entity_datetime` where entity_id = 275 
   union all
   select entity_id, attribute_id, store_id from `catalog_product_entity_decimal` where entity_id = 275 
   union all
   select entity_id, attribute_id, store_id from `catalog_product_entity_int` where entity_id = 275 
   union all
   select entity_id, attribute_id, store_id from `catalog_product_entity_text` where entity_id = 275 
   union all
   select entity_id, attribute_id, store_id from `catalog_product_entity_varchar` where entity_id = 275
   ```
3. Run this SQL query on your DB
4. Export the result somewhere
5. Go to the admin and save this product and ensure that it does work on the frontend
6. Run the query you ran on step 3. again
7. Compare the two results and find the `attribute_id` that are in the second result but not the first
8. For each attribute_id not present in the first but present in the second result, run, this query where you changed the `attribute_id` accordingly :

   ```
   select attribute_code from eav_attribute where attribute_id = 72
   ```
9. Adapt your export to add the default values Magento is putting in for you for those attributes

If after those 8 first step, you still don't find what and how to add them in your import, do not hesitate to edit your question and comment under this answer telling me you did, so I can maybe help you further.